# React updating only first element of list on triggering onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a flexible list with an input field so that whenever I write something in that input field it changes the value.

Like this:
[image]

But, in whichever input field I type it changes the only name of first field alone.

Like there are 3 input field and 3 paragraph tag according to state. I want to update the input field's above p tag (displaying the name) onChange of input field.

I am trying to implement this function using React hooks.

Here is my code:

**App.js**

```
const initialPersonState = [
    {name:"Vivank",age:"21"},
    {name:"Shubham",age:"18"},
    {name:"Max",age:"16"},
  ]

  const [personState, setPersonState] = useState(initialPersonState)
const inputChangeHandeler = (event,id) => {
    const personIndex = personState.findIndex(p =>{
      return p.id === id
    })

    const person = {
      ...personState[personIndex]
    }

    person.name = event.target.value

    const persons = [...personState]
    persons[personIndex] = person

    setPersonState(persons)
  }

person = (
      <>
        {personState.map((person,index)=>{
          return <Person 
          name={person.name}
          age={person.age}
          delete={() => deletePerson(index)}
          key={person.id}
          change={(event)=>inputChangeHandeler(event,person.id)}
          />
        })

        }
      </>
```

**Person.js**

```
const person = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p onClick={()=>props.click("Max!")}>Hello my name is {props.name} and I'm {props.age} years old</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <p onClick={props.delete}>Delete person</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.change}></input>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `name` to the input.  So your `person` component should look like this:

```
const person = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p onClick={()=>props.click("Max!")}>Hello my name is {props.name} and I'm {props.age} years old</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <p onClick={props.delete}>Delete person</p>
            <input type="text" value={props.name} onChange={props.change}></input>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Also, you haven't defined `id` inside person info objects, initial state should look like

```
const initialPersonState = [
    {id: 1, name:"Vivank",age:"21"},
    {id: 2, name:"Shubham",age:"18"},
    {id: 3, name:"Max",age:"16"},
  ];
```

Comment: Yeah, but it still isn't updating its respected p tag above it.

Comment: Like there are 3 input field and 3 paragraph tag according to state. I want to update the input field's above p tag onChange

Comment: Which <p> tag you mean? First one in the component?

Comment: Yeah, `<p onClick={()=>props.click("Max!")}>Hello my name is {props.name} and I'm {props.age} years old</p>`

Comment: Can you help me out here?

Comment: Sure, looking into it now.

Comment: Well, you haven't defined `id` for each person info objects.